# check box does not work properly using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I want is to make checkbox checked when the required `data == 1`. For example, if `data.add_content ==1` then make checkbox checked.  The problem in my code is that checkbox only checked  after I refresh the page. I do not want to refresh the page, could I use callback function to achieve that or what to do? please explain with code sample. thanks

`UPDATED CODE` [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/f27uzv9L/)

Comment: A fiddle would be nice

Comment: of course you can! In fact you already used callback the done one `jqXhrHandler(jqxhr, done, fail, always)`. Try to debug it with console.log('yeah') see what you get

Comment: By the way `jqXhrHandler` where did you find that function?

Comment: from here `function jqXhrHandler(jqxhr, done, fail, always) {
    if ($.isFunction(done))
        jqxhr.done(done);
    if ($.isFunction(fail))
        jqxhr.fail(fail);
    if ($.isFunction(always))
        jqxhr.always(always);

    return jqxhr;
}`

Answer (score -3):

Have you tried change the following

```
data.add_content ==1
```

to

```
data.add_content =="1"
```

Comment: yeah, I have tried that and still does not work for me

Comment: In javascript, `1=="1"` is true, so that wouldn't change anything